# GivenStories parametrized

Tags: bdd, jbehave, parameterized, user-stories

I've an issue with "GivenStories parametrized by examples".

I've tried to achieve the next flow by the following [example](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/given-stories.html)

My implementation looks like :

**Main.story**

```
Meta:

GivenStories: dummy/Precondition.story#{0}

Scenario: main scenario
Given have string <first>
When add string <second>
Then print result

Examples:
|first|second|
|aaaa|bbbb|
|cccc|dddd|
|eeee|rrrr|
```

**Precondition.story**

```
Meta:

Scenario: precondition scenario
Given have number <first>
When add number <second>
Then print result
```

*The execution of the stories ...*

```
Processing system properties {}
Using controls EmbedderControls[batch=false,skip=false,generateViewAfterStories=true,ignoreFailureInStories=false,ignoreFailureInView=false,verboseFailures=false,verboseFiltering=false,storyTimeoutInSecs=300,failOnStoryTimeout=false,threads=1]

(BeforeStories)

Running story dummy/Main.story

(dummy/Main.story)
GivenStories:
dummy/Precondition.story#{0} {}


(dummy/Precondition.story)
Scenario: precondition scenario
Given have number <first> (PENDING)
When add number <second> (NOT PERFORMED)
Then print result (NOT PERFORMED)


Scenario: main scenario
Examples:
Given have string <first>
When add string <second>
Then print result

|first|second|
|aaaa|bbbb|
|cccc|dddd|
|eeee|rrrr|

Example: {first=aaaa, second=bbbb}
Given have string aaaa
When add string bbbb
---->aaaabbbb
Then print result

Example: {first=cccc, second=dddd}
Given have string cccc
When add string dddd
---->ccccdddd
Then print result

Example: {first=eeee, second=rrrr}
Given have string eeee
When add string rrrr
---->eeeerrrr
Then print result

(AfterStories)
```

By the logs you can see that the precondition story actually not being executed.
What I'm doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

simple solution , just to locate the "GivenStories" under the "Scenario:"

```
Meta:

Scenario: main scenario
GivenStories: dummy/Precondition.story#{1}

Given have string <first>
When add string <second>
Then print result

Examples:
|first|second|
|aaaa|bbbb|
|cccc|dddd|
|eeee|rrrr|
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!
Thanks, it does work after replacing the "GivenStories" under the "Scenario" !